# Can we display error message when changing the object label name only specific user through apex code in salesforce?

Tags: apex, lightning

My scenario is when user is changing the object label name its immediately send email notification to  system admin and at the same time popup custom error message on screen.. Please any one help me on this

Answer (score 3):

No, this isn't possible. If you don't trust a user to make a certain change, they should not have Customize Application or Customize Object (Delegated Administration) privileges.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done for now there is an idea here on idea exchange requesting this feature:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l2iNAAQ

as @sfdcfox sugggested we can revoke Customize Application or Customize Object (Delegated Administration) privileges.